# Is it recommended to use DoctrineMigrationsBundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it recommended to use DoctrineMigrationsBundle? Or is it recommended to use Doctrine Migrations at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to sync your database scripts over multiple database etc it is a good tool, but still not perfect so you will need to check the migrations yourself if you want to be sure.

The doctrine/migrations library doens't have a stable release or alpha so it's still pretty much a young piece of software, but we use it to sync our changes on our development/testing and production databases. It makes it easier to have a central place where you keep and manage your database structure changes.

There is a solution for composer so a stable requirement will not prevent you from using doctrine migrations but it's only a temp solution until we get a reaction from the developers

see: [doctrine/migrations#120](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/120)

So all and all i can say it's a decent piece of software but you shouldn't trust it blindly!